# /bin/sh: git: not found - GitLab CI with Nx Workspaces

Tags: docker, containers, gitlab-ci, nx-workspace

I have used nx workspaces for my monorepo which relies on the [nx-affected](https://nx.dev/using-nx/affected) utility to know the difference between two states. I want to trigger a staging deployment when code is pushed to that branch hence I am using the command below

```sh
yarn nx affected:build --base=origin/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH~1 --head=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --prod
```

running this locally works just fine but running this in ci is producing the error below

```
$ yarn nx affected:build --base=origin/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH~1 --head=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --prod
yarn run v1.22.15
$ /builds/vesatogo/weave/node_modules/.bin/nx affected:build '--base=origin/staging~1' --head=staging --prod
/bin/sh: git: not found
/bin/sh: git: not found
```

Attaching my entire ci file for reference

```yaml
image: node:16-alpine
stages:
  # - install
  - build
  # - deploy
  # - test

.intall-node-yarn:
  before_script:
    - apk add --update nodejs npm
    - npm i -g yarn
cache:
  key:
    files:
      - yarn.lock
  paths:
    - node_modules
    - .yarn

# install-dependencies:
#   stage: install
#   script:
#     - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
#   rules:
#     - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^development|staging|production/"
#       changes:
#         - yarn.lock

# Build production version
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn nx affected:build --base=origin/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH~1 --head=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --prod
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  variables:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_KITE_ENV: $NEXT_PUBLIC_KITE_ENV
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "dist"
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  =~ /^staging|production/"
# Build and push docker images
# push:
#   stage: deploy
#   image: docker:20.10.12
#   services:
#     - docker:20.10.12-dind
#   variables:
#     DOCTL_TOKEN: $DOCTL_TOKEN
#   extends:
#     - .intall-node-yarn
#   script:
#     - yarn nx run kite:dockerize
#   rules:
#     - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  =~ /^staging|production/"

# # Deploy the application to kubernetes
# deploy:
#   stage: deploy
#   image: dtzar/helm-kubectl
#   needs:
#     - push
#   extends:
#     - .intall-node-yarn
#   script:
#     - yarn nx run kite:deploy
#   rules:
#     - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  =~ /^staging|production/"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use
before_script
in gitlab-ci file to install git command

```
  before_script:
- apk add --update git
- apk add --update nodejs npm
- npm i -g yarn
```

Comment: ur welcome.
tnx for vote my answer